# Geocoder.getFromLocationName not working for some places

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get locations from the string which is being searched. But, in some cases addressList is returning size 0(i.e. H.M. education centre, kolkata). I don't have latitude and longitude to search the place. Needed help.

```
String addressString = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
String addressString1 = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
List<Address> addressList = null;
Address address = null;
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(addressString))
{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try
    {
        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addressString, 1);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addressString = addressString1;
    }
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    if(addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0)
    {
         address = addressList.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code what you tried so far..

Comment: Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addressString, 5); 
check with increasing maxResults parameter.

Comment: I tried with that. not working.@Nik

Comment: please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063590/android-geocoder-getfromlocationname-fails-with-valid-address, if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative you can use Geocoding API or Places API web services. I checked your address 'H.M. education centre, kolkata' in Geocoding API web service request and figured out that coordinate can be found. Have a look at Geocoder tool with this address:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DH.M.%2520education%2520centre%252C%2520kolkata

In your Java code I can suggest using the Java Client for Google Maps Services hosted at Github:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

The code snippet to execute web service request with this client library is the following

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
    .apiKey("AIza...")
    .build();
GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
"H.M. education centre, kolkata").await();
```

The Javadoc for the current version of the library can be found at

https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.2.7/javadoc/

Note also that places like this one can be found via Places API web service. In this case the code snippet will be

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
    .apiKey("AIza...")
    .build();
TextSearchRequest req = PlacesApi.textSearchQuery(context, "H.M. education centre, kolkata");
try {
    PlacesSearchResponse resp = req.await();
    if (resp.results != null && resp.results.length > 0) {
        //Process your results here
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error getting places", e);
}
```

I hope this helps!